# 2 Constructors with same name in Apex Class

Tags: apex, class

First actual post here.

I am fairly new to Apex Classes and I'm working on an existing project.

The previous developer has the following inside of an apex class:

```
private List<id> accountsMainList = new List<id>();
Boolean archiveSync = false;
public BDGAccSync(Boolean archiveSync) {
    this.archiveSync = archiveSync;
}
public BDGAccSync(List<Account> accountsMainList) {
    for (Account acc : accountsMainList) {
        this.accountsMainList.add(acc.id);
    }
}
```

My question is - Does the second instance override the first or does Salesforce support overloading like java, etc?

UPDATE: Thank you all for the quick answers  Overloading it is!

Comment: Apex allows many patterns present in Java including [method and constructor overloading](https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-5/2-method-and-constructor-overloading).

Comment: N.B. You can simplify the second constructor to `this.accountsMainList.addAll(accountsMainList);` and eliminate the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty standard practice (in programming in general, not just Salesforce/Apex) called *overloading*.

You have the same constructor (or method) name, but just pass in a different number or different types of arguments.

You'll only end up using one of the two constructors at any given time that you call `new BDGAccSync(...);`. As long as you pass appropriate arguments to it, the correct version will automatically be called. I.e. `new BDGAccSync(false);` will call the version that takes a `Boolean` and not the one that takes a `List<Account>` without any other intervention from you.